# Angular + Service worker: how to pass `apiUrl` from `environment.ts` to `sw-sync.js`?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, service-worker, angular-service-worker

My Angular app have a service worker with a `fetch` logic.
I want to have one place for my dynamical data in the main app and in the service worker (`apiUrl` etc.) for better integration with CI in the future.

How can I get app variables from my service worker? Or maybe I need to change my understanding of data structure in my app?